# Excel Capture change in one cell and copy changes in other sheet

Tags: vba, excel

I  have multiple sheets in a workbook.
Cell(A1) of every sheet has exactly the same text "Report for (month) (year)".
every month only the month and year value changes.
example: for February the text will be "Report for Feb 2013".
How can I make changes in one sheet and the same change is copied to the remaining sheets ?
I know how to copy cells but that way the code becomes lengthy .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can iterate all workshseets easily

Assume you have done it for the current sheet

```
Sub copyAOne()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim newValue As Range
    set newValue = ActiveSheet.Range("A1")
    For Each ws In Worksheets
        ws.Range("A1") = newValue
    Next ws
**PS** Please provide the code you tried in your question, and see if we can optimize it as well
end sub
```

Comment: Range("A1").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Sheet1").Select
    Range("A1").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Sheets("Sheet2").Select
    Range("A1").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Sheets("Sheet3").Select
    Range("A1").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Sheets("Sheet4").Select
    Range("A1").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste

Comment: '    Range("A1").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Sheet1").Select
    Range("A1").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Sheets("Sheet2").Select
    Range("A1").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Sheets("Sheet3").Select
    Range("A1").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Sheets("Sheet4").Select
    Range("A1").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste'
and attached it to a button so that on click the changes are pasted to all sheets

Comment: I am very new at VBA.
Please tell me where to paste this code and how will it work.

Comment: @Nishant Kumar, you can place the sub into a Module, create a button/or call it from the developer's Tab--> Macro.

Comment: Hi, this code yous sent works great without any problems. But The change i make is bold. and the value copied in all cells is normal text. what can i do here ?